# jQuery autocomplete with remote json not working in IE

Tags: jquery, wcf

```
 $('#text_search').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Service1.svc/GetSites",
                    maxHeight: 400,
                    width: 300,
                    zIndex: 9999,
                  //  data: {},
                   // data: "{ 'SName': 's'}",
                    data: '{"input": "' + request.term + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        response($.map(data.GetSitesResult, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.SiteName
                        }
                         }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
```

In the above code had created a WCF service am passing parameters and fetching JSON result.I had created a DataContract sites and operation contract as OperationContract.Using the list am filling the values and returning the JSON result.Here am using post method to post the data for WCF service

For the above code am getting response as  {"GetSitesResult":[{"SiteName":"site1"},{"SiteName":"site2"},{"SiteName":"site3"}]}.This same code is working in both chrome and firefox but autocomplete feature is not working in IE.Please help me if had done anything wrong in the above code

Comment: I had tried this its not working

Answer (score 0):

try this one but put autocomplete css (from jquery ui) in CSS

```
 $('#textbox id').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("url?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
            response(data);
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    delay: 100
});
```